# Get a unique data in a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, unique, data-entry

I've a database who contain some datas in that form:

```
icon(name, size, tag)
(myicon.png, 16, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 32, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 128, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 256, 'twitter')
(anothericon.png, 32, 'facebook')
(anothericon.png, 128, 'facebook')
(anothericon.png, 256, 'facebook')
```

So as you see it, the name field is not uniq I can have multiple icons with the same name and they are separated with the size field. Now in PHP I have a query that get ONE icon set, for example :

```
$dbQueryIcons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_icon WHERE tag LIKE '%".$SEARCH_QUERY."%' GROUP BY name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$firstEntry.", ".$CONFIG['icon_per_page']."") or die(mysql_error());
```

With this example if $tag contain 'twitter' it will show ONLY the first SQL data entry with the tag 'twitter', so it will be :

```
(myicon.png, 16, 'twitter')
```

This is what I want, but I would prefer the '128' size by default. Is this possible to tell SQL to send me only the 128 size when existing and if not another size ?

In an another question someone give me a solution with the GROUP BY but in this case that don't run because we have a GROUP BY name. And if I delete the GROUP BY, it show me all size of the same icons.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try using subqueries.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT * FROM pl_icon
    WHERE tag LIKE '%$SEARCH_QUERY%'
    ORDER BY IF(size = 128, 0, 1)

) pl_icon
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT ...
```

We find all matching rows in the inner query and place rows with size = 128 above all others. Then, for each unique name we choose only the first record using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Nice that's run ! Thank you !!! Juste one thing. I saw that if there isn't a 128 size it show me the first one 16 for example. It is possible to have 128 or less ? For example if 128 does not exist it show me 64 (if exist) or 32 or 16 ? Thanks

Comment: @Jensen, yes, it is possible: `ORDER BY IF (size = 128, 0, 1), IF(size < 128, 0, 1), size DESC` - this will ensure the following order: "128; then everything lower than 128 in descending order; then everything higher then 128 in descending order", i.e. "128, 64, 32, 16, 256"

Comment: Or even better: `ORDER BY IF (size <= 128, 0, 1), size DESC` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ORDER BY clause (id or size?):

```
ORDER BY case when size=128 then 999999 else size end DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is get the record with the largest size then:

```
SELECT name, tag, MAX(size)
FROM pl_icon 
WHERE tag LIKE '%".$SEARCH_QUERY."%' 
GROUP BY name, tag
```

But what's confusing here is that the 'name' is not unique. Usually in such scenarios people want to identify the record where a maximum (or minimum) occurs - like the last meter reading, or biggest invoice. So if your table had an id field and you wanted to retrieve that:

```
SELECT pl2.*
FROM pl_icon pl2,
(SELECT name, tag, MAX(size) AS biggest
FROM pl_icon 
WHERE tag LIKE '%".$SEARCH_QUERY."%' 
GROUP BY name, tag) ilv
WHERE ilv.name=pl2.name
AND ilv.tag=pl2.tag
AND ilv.biggest=pl2.size;
```

However this can be rather inefficient for very large tables / selects - when you might want to try the [MAX(CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) trick

C.